# message-driven-channel-adapter deadlock issues

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have this deadlock scenario which brings the application to a complete halt, not sure whats going on, if you could show some light. Thank you
This is the consumer configuration

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter                                  
    id="InBoundZFlow" 
    connection-factory="wmqConnFactory" 
    destination="ResponseQueue"  
    channel="responseInChannel" 
    auto-startup="false" 
    max-messages-per-task="20"
    receive-timeout="10000"
    concurrent-consumers="2"
    task-executor="receivingTaskExecutor"
    max-concurrent-consumers="20" 
    idle-consumer-limit="1"
    idle-task-execution-limit="1"                               
    recovery-interval="60000"/>
```

`receivingTaskExecutor` has `20` threads.
This is what i see for some of the blocking threads -

```
   "receivingTaskExecutor-19" - Thread t@226
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    - waiting to lock <1f7cd479> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "receivingTaskExecutor-11" t@111
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1002)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

---

```
"rceivingTaskExecutor-16" - Thread t@184
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.isRunning(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:347)
    - waiting to lock <3c616415> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "receivingTaskExecutor-7" t@69
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:995)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <712a95c7> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

----------------------------------------------------


"mqReceivingTaskExecutor-7" - Thread t@69
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    - waiting to lock <1f7cd479> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "mqReceivingTaskExecutor-11" t@111
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    - locked <3c616415> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <a01ec0b> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

---------------------------------------------------------

"receivingTaskExecutor-11" - Thread t@111
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - waiting to lock <1df1bdab> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync) owned by "receivingTaskExecutor-5" t@65
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:838)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:871)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:290)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.requestSendLock(RemoteConnection.java:2842)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.sendTSH(RemoteConnection.java:1812)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.sendTSH(RemoteSession.java:758)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession.exchangeTSH(RemoteSession.java:1237)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.spiNotify(RemoteFAP.java:4612)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiNotify(RemoteFAP.java:4449)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.monitoring.JmqiInterceptAdapter.jmqiNotify(JmqiInterceptAdapter.java:579)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.setRunning(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:462)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.stop(WMQMessageConsumer.java:535)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsMessageConsumerImpl.stopUnconditional(JmsMessageConsumerImpl.java:706)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.stop(JmsSessionImpl.java:2014)
    - locked <2a02832d> (a java.util.Collections$SynchronizedSet)
    - locked <af214e7> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.close(JmsSessionImpl.java:315)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsConnectionImpl.close(JmsConnectionImpl.java:300)
    - locked <1b3a4f4e> (a com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.State)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnection.close(MQConnection.java:98)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:395)
    - locked <1f7cd479> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:885)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:861)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1013)
    - locked <112c97d9> (a java.lang.Object)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <33d65cd0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

    - locked <6a5305e> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

---

```
"receivingTaskExecutor-5" - Thread t@65
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    - waiting to lock <1f7cd479> (a java.lang.Object) owned by "receivingTaskExecutor-11" t@111
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1002)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - locked <19f71b53> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

    - locked <1df1bdab> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the mq client library.

`receivingTaskExecutor-5` is holding a lock owned by the client library but has no client library stack frames on its stack.

`receivingTaskExecutor-11` is trying to acquire that lock (while holding a `DMLC` lock; the other threads are waiting for that).

So something happened in the client library on `receivingTaskExecutor-5` that caused it to leave the lock locked.

I suggest you contact IBM support.

Comment: Is there anything i can do in my configuration to avoid this for time being?

Comment: Try with the single `concurrency`

Comment: I can not live with just one thread for reading MQ here as the volume is large. Can i define multiple <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter    ..> , will it give me same results? Thanks!

Comment: Yes; effectively. I don't know the internals of the IBM client (that's the problem with closed source :) ) so I don't know if you'll need a separate connection factory for each adapter.

Comment: You can make the `channel` of that adapter as `ExecutorChannel` and take care about multi-threading in the Spring Integration application already.

Comment: That's true, but exceptions won't cause redelivery then.

Comment: Also does it make any thread related difference if this runs under  a task-executor or its own thread?

Comment: After changing to multiple <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter ..> with max concurrent set to 1 for each, this has been working fine so far.

Comment: Good news, but you should get IBM to fix their bug. In response to your previous comment, if you are running in a websphere app server, you should use a `WorkManagerTaskExecutor`. If not, it makes no difference (but the `TE` needs to have sufficient threads).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I am running a standalone java process not the app server. The issue is being sent to IBM and will take some time to find a resolution but i am glad meantime its working fine with this workaround.